# Is there any purpose, or benefit, in using a mala when reciting a sahasranama?

Tags: vedic-chanting, vishnu-sahasranama, japamala, sahasranama

As per the title, is there any benefit (or reason) to using a mala when reciting a sahasranama — such as using a tulsi mala while reciting the Vishnu Sahasranamam, for example, or an appropriate mala with another sahasranama?

Presumably you would only recite something the length of the Vishnu Sahasranamam once in a sitting (reciting it 108 times could take over two days straight).

Since it is said to have 108 verses, if you counted one bead for each verse you may realise if you missed one. Or is there a different way you might use a mala with this kind of recitation? Would there be any benefit just in holding it?

Comment: Mala is used to keep the count. I'm not particularly if anyone using it for **sahasranama**!

Comment: For stotra recitals keeping count using mala is not necessary .. it is mandatory in mantra japa to keep the count though.